# Creating navigation menu with both text and images

Tags: css, menu, navigation

Could you please advise on how to create a navigation menu like this one at the bottom?
https://m1.behance.net/rendition/modules/30754283/disp/e05f3faf8755b4c1892a7e9c66de7627.png

I already have the footer div set, I only need the menu itself. I tried and experimeneted but couldn't get it to display exactly as I want. The images would have to be with CSS background so that I can have the image change when the "tab" is active.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Show what you tried, it will be much easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks, I added a draft of what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see that it is in any way necessary to do this with `background-image` attribute.

You could just use a normal `<img src="pics/my-img.png" />` in the HTML structure of this navigation bar. Setting the alignment to simply nothing on the image will in most cases drop the text on the same container below the picture, but in case of an exception:

```
#myNavigation img {
   display: block;
   padding-bottom: 4px;
}
```

This should help you with what I understood of your question, that you're trying to create a navigation menu with images and text.

There's also a quite simple and nice hover effect possibilities for this, for e.g:

```
#myNavigation img {
   opacity: 0.6;
}
#myNavigation img:hover {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for the input, the only reason I thought I'd need the background-image it's because this way I would be able to have it of a different color when it's active. (it becomes blue instead of gray in the example link)

Comment: Is there a way to do it? Thank you again :)

Comment: In this case you should use indeed the background-image... You should be able to achieve this by adjusting the text with `padding-top: 50px;` or what ever the height of your background image is. Then you should set to the `background: url(img/my-image.png) top center no-repeat` so your background is centered and adjusted with the text.